# WebView2 AddHostObjectToScript in UWP crashes

Tags: c#, uwp, webview2

I'm trying to pass a C# object to a WebView2 using `AddHostObjectToScript`. After not succeeding to retrieve the object from the webview, I've used the debugger and found out that the `AddHostObjectToScript` call is never completing.

Here is the full code snippet:

```cs
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Example
{
    public string Prop { get; set; } = "example";
}

namespace Example_UWP
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeAsync();
        }

        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            await ExampleView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();

            ExampleView.Source = new Uri("http://localhost:3000");
            ExampleView.CoreWebView2.OpenDevToolsWindow();

            ExampleView.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("example", new Example());
        }
    }
}
```

The `example` object is as a result not available in `chrome.webview.hostObjects` or `chrome.webview.hostObjects.sync`. The function throws the following error:

> The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

I've tried different alternatives without success, such as:

- Keeping a reference to the `Example` instance in an attribute inside `Example_UWP` to avoid potential GC
- Adding the host object before and after each of the previous steps within `InitializeAsync`
- Wait for the event `NavigationCompleted` to add the host object.
- Wait for 5 seconds before adding the host object.

I'm using Microsoft.Web.WebView2 version 1.0.1264.42

Comment: Please raise an issue here: [WebView2Feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues)

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to interact with your third-party lib, you need to add a very specific C++ project, **Windows Runtime Component (C++/WinRT)**, to your solution that must be called **WinRTAdapter**.

[image: preview2]

Next, you must install a lib to your C++ project from NuGet called `Microsoft.Web.WebView2`:

[image: preview1]

After this is done, you must your third-party lib as a reference.

Next, go to your C++ project properties go to **Common Properties** and choose **WebView2**:

[image: preview4]

Here you have to do four changes:

- Set Use **WebView2 WinRT APIs** to **No**.
- Set **Use the wv2winrt tool** to **Yes**.
- Set **Use Javascript case** to **Yes**.
- Edit **Include filters** and add the following ones:

```
Windows.System.UserProfile
Windows.Globalization.Language
CallJSInterface
```

**CallJSInterface** is the name of my third-party's namespace.

[image: preview6]

You click on OK and build your C++ lib.

After you have built your **C++ lib (WinRTAdapter)**, you must add it to your main project as a reference.

Now, we need to do some changes to be able to invoke the functions from our third-party lib. The first one is to register it. We do it in the same `LoadLocalPage()` function from before or on NavigationCompleted:

```
var namespacesName = "CallJSInterface";
var dispatchAdapter = new WinRTAdapter.DispatchAdapter();
core_wv2.AddHostObjectToScript(namespacesName, dispatchAdapter.WrapNamedObject(namespacesName, dispatchAdapter));
```

Where `CallJSInterface` is your namespace. After this, you need to register your function in your JS like this:

```
var callJS;
if (chrome && chrome.webview) {
    chrome.webview.hostObjects.options.defaultSyncProxy = true;
    chrome.webview.hostObjects.options.forceAsyncMethodMatches = [/Async$/];
    chrome.webview.hostObjects.options.ignoreMemberNotFoundError = true;
    window.CallJSInterface = chrome.webview.hostObjects.sync.CallJSInterface;
    callJS = new CallJSInterface.CallJSCSharp();
}
```

Where `CallJSInterface` is one more time your namespace. Now, you can invoke JS like this (the `async()` is mandatory):

```
callJS.async().KeepScreenOn()
```

If you need more details, I have a full tutorial on my website:

https://supernovaic.blogspot.com/2022/10/from-webview-to-webview2-in-uwp.html